# D3 Draw Path with coordinate ML

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to draw the following path with d3 using MultiLineString:

```
var first=["M", 51.579519, -24.245497, "L", 51.757441, -24.294073, 51.794389, -24.019826, 52.577081, -24.177439, 53.404007, -24.151317, 54.008001, -24.121758, 54.693024, -24.797892, 55.439025, -25.439145, 56.070821, -26.055464, 56.261042, -25.714606, 56.396847, -24.924732, 55.886233, -24.920831, 55.804119, -24.269604, 55.981214, -24.130543, 55.528632, -23.933604, 55.525841, -23.524869, 55.234489, -23.110993, 55.208341, -22.70833, 55.006803, -22.496948, 52.000733, -23.001154, 51.617708, -24.014219, 51.579519, -24.245497, "Z"];

var second=["M", 149, -1841, "L", 152, -1837, 147, -1835, 147, -1828, 139, -1834, 149, -1841, "M", 152, -1823, "L", 147, -1819, 150, -1817, 154, -1804, 149, -1808, 147, -1820, 152, -1824, 152, -1825, 151, -1832, 156, -1826, 160, -1838, 156, -1840, 156, -1850, 310, -1808, 285, -1701, 286, -1684, 225, -1699, 208, -1700, 187, -1697, 176, -1700, 159, -1701, 158, -1705, 143, -1709, 128, -1707, 115, -1715, 117, -1728, 116, -1734, 109, -1740, 104, -1740, 102, -1746, 91, -1748, 87, -1754, 94, -1761, 96, -1769, 91, -1770, 92, -1776, 102, -1777, 93, -1783, 95, -1813, 91, -1822, 92, -1833, 99, -1840, 111, -1828, 132, -1818, 138, -1813, 145, -1816, 146, -1804, 149, -1804, 143, -1792, 147, -1781, 134, -1785, 125, -1776, 136, -1773, 141, -1780, 148, -1781, 150, -1798, 158, -1805, 152, -1823, "Z"];
```

First one was drawn correctly without issues(UAE), second one(Washinton States) was not working correctly. I'm wondering why is that?

Comment: Can you please add screenshots of your results?

Comment: Also more code snippets are needed to understand how describe how you are rendering the above code?

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem in your second array , It has a comma inside it.

```
,` "Z"]
```

Your second variable should be:

```
var second=["M", 149, -1841, "L", 152, -1837, 147, -1835, 147, -1828, 139, -1834, 149, -1841, "M", 152, -1823, "L", 147, -1819, 150, -1817, 154, -1804, 149, -1808, 147, -1820, 152, -1824, 152, -1825, 151, -1832, 156, -1826, 160, -1838, 156, -1840, 156, -1850, 310, -1808, 285, -1701, 286, -1684, 225, -1699, 208, -1700, 187, -1697, 176, -1700, 159, -1701, 158, -1705, 143, -1709, 128, -1707, 115, -1715, 117, -1728, 116, -1734, 109, -1740, 104, -1740, 102, -1746, 91, -1748, 87, -1754, 94, -1761, 96, -1769, 91, -1770, 92, -1776, 102, -1777, 93, -1783, 95, -1813, 91, -1822, 92, -1833, 99, -1840, 111, -1828, 132, -1818, 138, -1813, 145, -1816, 146, -1804, 149, -1804, 143, -1792, 147, -1781, 134, -1785, 125, -1776, 136, -1773, 141, -1780, 148, -1781, 150, -1798, 158, -1805, 152, -1823, "Z"];
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the comma, but it's not the issue.